# How to post many-to-many relational data to a restful api from AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, rest, sequelize.js

I have a Theme Management module in my web application. I'ö using SequelizeJS in server side.

Models are:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var Theme = sequelize.define('Theme', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING

}, {
    associate: function(models) {
        Theme.belongsToMany(models.Option, { through: models.ThemeOptions })
    },
    tableName: 'themes'
});

return Theme;
};


module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var ThemeOptions = sequelize.define('ThemeOptions', {
}, {
    tableName: 'theme_options'
});

return ThemeOptions;
};


module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var Option = sequelize.define('Option', {
    key: DataTypes.STRING,
    value: DataTypes.STRING

}, {
    associate: function(models) {
        Option.belongsToMany(models.Theme, { through: models.ThemeOptions })
    },
    tableName: 'options',
    timestamps: false
});

return Option;
};
```

In /#/themes/create state, I want to create a theme with some options, like color codes.

I am creating a theme with

```
 $http.post('/themes', themeData)
```

then with it's it, I am creating options. Finally I should post many-to-many data to theme options. So for a theme that has 10 options, I am posting 21 times.

What is the best way to post many-to-many data to a REST server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really know how you handle your routing or backend. Supposing you're using express and your options are previously created, I'd recommend creating a new post route for handling each `ThemeOptions`

```
app.post('/themeOptions', { ThemeId: 1, OptionId:2 });
```

and use that info to create a `ThemeOptions` instance to join a `Theme` with certain `Option`.

This could reduce your post quantity to the half + 1 (one for the `Theme` and one for each `ThemeOption`).

Another solution is to maybe manage an array of `ThemeOptions` and use `ThemeOptions#bulkCreate` to create them at once, using only 2 posts (one for the `Theme` and one for all the `ThemeOptions`.

Would be something like this:

```
app.post('/themeOptions', { 
  options: [{
    ThemeId: 1, 
    OptionId:2
  }, {
    ThemeId: 1, 
    OptionId:3
  } 
  // and so on...
});
```

Each of these solutions could involve more logic to manage each front end request, but could increase front end behavior as well.

A final (and more complex at the backend) solution would be to send a unique post sending both, the `Theme` and the `Option`s array, and create all the `ThemeOptions` after creating the `Theme`

```
// frontend
app.post('/theme', { 
  theme: {
    name: 'John',
    description: 'Doe'
  },
  options: [2, 3 /* and so on ... */]
}); 

// backend
Theme.create(req.body.theme).on('success', function (theme) {
   var options = req.body.options.map(function (option) {
     return {
       ThemeId: theme.id, 
       OptionId: option
     };
   });

   ThemeOptions.bulkCreate(options);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Symfony2 world, there is a bundle, SonataAdminBundle, that generates admin interfaces. With the entity classes (here, `Option` and `Theme`), it generates all the pages, listing, creating and editing theses entities. It generates forms that handles many to many relationship. Here how it manages that :

The user consults the creation/edition form of the entity of any side of the ManyToMany relation. In the form, where it have to display the many to many association, it displays a `<select>`, with [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) for instance, which is a `<select>` with some jQuery. Each element of the list is *linked with the corresponding ID in the database*, something like `<option value="13456">Option #3</select>`. For a many to many relationship, we can select multiple fields at the time. Internally, it builds an **array of Option IDs** with the `<select>`.

If we want to add a inverse entity on the fly (here, the inverse entity is Option, I think ...), there is a button that open ups an Option creation form, and once the new Option is added, it **adds the newly created option in the `<select>`**, so the user can *add it in the form immediately*.
Then, it sends the array of Option ID's built with the form.

I think this strategy could fit your needs.